# How to run simple Scala class from terminal?

Tags: scala

I have the Scala program `myTest.scala` with the following content:

```
class Test {
    def hello() {
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

How can I execute it from the console? If I run `scala myTest.scala` in the terminal, it obviously cannot find the `main` method which I do not have.
Is there any way to run it as `scala Test.hello`?
Is it mandatory to use `scalac` to compile before running `scala`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first give your Object a main method. There are 2 ways to do this:

```
object HelloWorld {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   println("Hello, world!")
 }
}
```

or

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
   println("Hello, world!")
}
```

Once you have your object ready. You can compile your class in your terminal as below:

`$ scalac HelloWorld.scala`

and run the program.

`$ scala HelloWorld`

More on this [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/your-first-lines-of-scala.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a class in Scala.

You need to define an object with a main method or that extends App

```
object Test extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
```